# Detail page - Display configurable product's thumbnail images even when an option is selected!

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, product-view, magento-2.2.1

So let's say I have a configurable product having an option of colour with 2 values: Black, White.

I want to make the thumbnail images of the parent product stay, even when I select any colour.

Here is my parent product:
[image]

And this is my child product:

[image]

So can you guide me how to do that?
Without re-adding images. 
I'm using Magento 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

In order to stop, reload of you need  work on [configurable.js](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js)
 file:

On this js at [_configureElement()](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js#L249), you need to remove   [`this._changeProductImage();`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js#L274)

```
this._reloadPrice();
this._displayRegularPriceBlock(this.simpleProduct);
this._displayTierPriceBlock(this.simpleProduct);
this._displayNormalPriceLabel();
//this._changeProductImage(); // remove this line
```

**Who to do it:**
First,you should check configurable.js exits at your theme level
means

> app/design/frontend/{YourThemeVendor}/{YourThemeName}/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/web/js/configurable.js

If exits then  comment the `_changeProductImage`.

**Or if it does not exits then copy the file**  from

> vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js

then  paste at

> app/design/frontend/{YourThemeVendor}/{YourThemeName}/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/web/js/configurable.js

Do  comment  `_changeProductImage`.